# perlite on its own for succulents

Tags: watering, succulents, potting-soil

What is your experience with using perlite on its own for planting succulents?

I add slow-release pellets for start-up, but will feed with liquid fertilizer when plants establish themselves. The perlite grains are size 4 (coarse).

**Plants:** Plants belonging to the genus Haworthia, Gasteria, Aloe, Sansevieria, Echeveria, Pachyphytum, Graptopetalum. My cacti and Euphorbias do well with 50/50 peat/sand mix, and I don't feel any need to move them to pure perlite. On the other hand, Haworthias and Gasterias are the most in need of a more professional potting mix to make it through the winter.

**Local climate, conditions:** Mediterranean climate, often with a very wet winter. That is where perlite may prove helpful. Winter weather is always above freezing. Summer is dry but very humid, as I live close to the sea.

**Additions to the soil mix:** As I said, I'm interested in pure perlite. However, pumice is hard to get in my area and I never saw it being sold. I tried to use ground tuffa/scoria, but the grains come with sharp edges which damage the thick roots of some Haworthia species. I have found that the grain size is too large, and dust is plenty. I may add, if necessary, ingredients like peat, coir and Vermiculite. These are much easier to find.